# How to make text box on webpage same in IE as Chrome

Tags: html, asp.net, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have the following HTML on my ASP.Net website:

```
               <tr>
                    <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" Text="Email" ID="LoginEmail" 
                            CssClass="usernamepassword" Width="160px"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    <td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="reqLoginEmail" ControlToValidate="LoginEmail" ValidationGroup="Login" ErrorMessage="*" Display="Static"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" Text="Password" ID="LoginPassword" 
                            TextMode="Password" CssClass="usernamepassword" Width="130px" ></asp:TextBox></td>
                    <td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="reqPassword" ControlToValidate="LoginPassword" ValidationGroup="Login" ErrorMessage="*" Display="Static"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
                    <td><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnLogin" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" ValidationGroup="Login" Text="Login" class="buttonRyan green medium" > </asp:LinkButton></td>
                </tr>
```

This displays fine in Google Chrome like so:
[image]

But on Internet Explorer it looks like this:
[image]

Notice how the text boxes are not as deep, how can I get the IE version to be the same as Chrome? (Firefox is also quite thin as well)

Here is my css:

```
.usernamepassword
{
border-style: none;
border-color: inherit;
border-width: medium;
font: 12px/20px "ArialMTRegular", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color:#3343030;
padding:0px 1px;
}
```

Comment: you can user any css except this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to fix height and line-height of all text boxes as below :

```
.usernamepassword {
   height : 18px;
   line-height : 18px;
}
```

Line height will take care of the text filled in text-box.

IE is more sensitive to CSS. So you have to define all rules in CSS so that it should be same in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to set a fixed `height`.
Try setting a `height` to the `.usernamepassword`:

```
.usernamepassword
{
  ...
  height: 1.5em;
}
```